# from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import keys

Tags: selenium

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import keys
chrome_driver_path ="C:\Developement\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path= chrome_driver_path)
driver.get("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page")
article_count = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#articlecount a")
# article_count.click()
all_portals = driver.find_element_by_link_text("All portals")
# all_portals.click()
search = driver.find_element_by_name("search")
search.send_keys("corona virus")
search.send_keys(keys.ENTER)
```

output:
Traceback (most recent call last)

> from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import keys ImportError: cannot
> import name 'keys' from 'selenium.webdriver.common.keys'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Keys` is case sensitive, use `from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys`.
See below.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
chrome_driver_path ="C:\Developement\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path= chrome_driver_path)
driver.get("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page")
article_count = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#articlecount a")
# article_count.click()
all_portals = driver.find_element_by_link_text("All portals")
# all_portals.click()
search = driver.find_element_by_name("search")
search.send_keys("corona virus")
search.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
```

Answer (score 0):

try this instead :

```
search = driver.find_element_by_name("search").send_keys("corona virus" + Keys.RETURN)
```